# Sum column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of varchar() type, value can be any string, is it possible to find sum of all rows that can be cast to numeric?

```
value
 ----
| 3  |
| 2 2|
| as |
| a1 |
| !2@|
| 0.5|
 ----
 3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression and convert:

```
select (case when value ~ '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$'
             then value::numeric
             else 0
        end)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4cdf525b2e61c8d15f213da5a060200b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You missed `SUM()`.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I also missed that 0.5 isn't an integer.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be:

```
with tb as(

select '3' as v union all
select '2 2' as v union all
select 'as' as v union all
select 'a1' as v union all
select '!2' as v union all
select '0.5' 
)


select sum(case when v ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'
             then v::numeric
             else 0
        end) as result
from tb;
```